# How to compare id in array Twig

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

In my project I have to display a list of `DOSSIERS` that have the same department as the logged user — who can have 1 to N departments. A `DOSSIER` has only one department.

So I would like to make a condition that would display that `DOSSIERS` that have a `department.id` present in the user's array of department.

Here is my code, which display nothing:

```
{% for user in user.departement  %}
    {% for dossier in dossier %}
    {# <p> DOSSIER TEST: {{ dossier.id }} </p> #}
        {% if user.id == dossier.id %}
          <p> DOSSIER ID: {{ dossier.id }} <tr>
      <th scope="row"> {{ dossier.id }} </th>
      <td>{{ dossier.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ dossier.CP}}</td>
      <td> {{ dossier.statut.nom}} </td>
      <td> {{ dossier.departement.id}} </td> </p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT

I did use the code you gave me but I don’t have anything showing, even the "DOSSIER ID:". Here the page returned:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sHNK.png

```
{% for dossier in dossier %}
        {% if dossier.departement.id in user.departement | column('id') %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">DOSSIER ID: {{ dossier.id }}</th>
                <td>{{ dossier.CP }}</td>
                <td>{{ dossier.statut.nom }}</td>
                <td>{{ dossier.departement.id }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
```

Here are my entities properties for more details:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=DossierRepository::class)
 */
class Dossier
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $adresse;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ville;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $proploc;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $CodeSecurite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Cp;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $NumPortable;

   

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $DateCreation;

    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Travaux::class, inversedBy="dossiers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $travaux;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="dossiers")
     */
    private $user;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Document::class, mappedBy="Dossier", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $document;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Impots::class, inversedBy="dossiers")
     */
    private $impot;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $Electricite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $Combustible;

   
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Statut::class, inversedBy="Dossier")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $statut;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $Etat;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Message::class, mappedBy="DossierId")
     */
    private $messages;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Departements::class, inversedBy="dossiers")
     */
    private $departement;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Refuser::class, mappedBy="Dossier")
     */
    private $refusers;
```

```
class Departements
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3)
     */
    private $RegionCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, mappedBy="departement")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Dossier::class, mappedBy="departement")
     */
    private $dossiers;
```

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email(message="Veuillez renseigner un email valide !")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Entreprise;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Adresse;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Ville;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Cp;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Dossier::class, mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $dossiers;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Message::class, mappedBy="UserId")
     */
    private $messages;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Conversation::class, mappedBy="User")
     */
    private $conversations;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Departements::class, inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $departement;
```

Thank you !

Comment: `if user.id == dossier.id` so a user is a `DOSSIER` not sure your user are going to be happy being compared to a bunch of paper.

Comment: Extra tip: don't use paragraph `<p>` in the middle of a table construct, this would give you invalid HTML. If you need some paragraph, put them in the `td` and `th` only.

Comment: You should also include in [edit] where `dossier` is coming from (so I guess your controller)

Comment: But mind that in my answer I wrote `{% for dossier in dossiers %}` mind the plural in `dossiers`  while your loop has a really buggy `{% for dossier in dossier %}` (to be honest, I don't even know how PHP would react doing a loop like that where the item looped on has the same variable name as the Iterable you are looping on)

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose using [`in`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#containment-operator) is what you are looking for:

```html
<table>
    {% for dossier in dossiers %}
        {% if dossier.departement.id in user.departement %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">DOSSIER ID: {{ dossier.id }}</th>
                <td>{{ dossier.CP }}</td>
                <td>{{ dossier.statut.nom }}</td>
                <td>{{ dossier.departement.id }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

<sup>*Demonstrated here: https://twigfiddle.com/dxlg4v*</sup>

---

Because you did not provide exactly the structure of the `user` object, you might also need the [`column`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/column.html) filter, e.g. if `departement` is an array of `Departement` entities and not a simple array of IDs.

```html
<table>
    {% for dossier in dossiers %}
        {% if dossier.departement.id in user.departement | column('id') %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">DOSSIER ID: {{ dossier.id }}</th>
                <td>{{ dossier.CP }}</td>
                <td>{{ dossier.statut.nom }}</td>
                <td>{{ dossier.departement.id }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

<sup>*Demonstrated here: https://twigfiddle.com/dxlg4v/2*</sup>